# PostgreSQL auto increment column by scope of another column value

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

In PostgreSQL we can define a column as **SERIAL** to auto increment it with insert query.

> Can this auto increment happen by scoping to another column value ?

I will explain my question with below example.

In a multi tenant SaaS application, there could be a scenario where we may need to increment a column (say `item_id` column in items table) per user account.

## Example:items table

item_id  |   account_id

100      |   1

101      |   1

102      |   1

100      |   2

*sorry for the bad formatting of the table. I hope you got idea about the basic structure.*

In the above example, as soon as a new item is created by a new account (say account 2), the `item_id` serial count should start from the beginning again i.e 100.

If user in account 1 deletes `item_id` 102 and creates a new item record, then `item_id` should set to 103 and so on.

I tried to find a solution but I could not get a pointer using Google search. So any help would be highly appreciated!

***PS:** I know this can be handled from backend code but I am more curious to know if database has a solution for this or not.*

Comment: Did you find any appropriate solution? I have similar issue

Answer (score 3):

You can't define `SERIAL` to be partitioned over other column. But you could use `ROW_NUMBER()` function. If you don't need that value materialized you could write something like:

```
CREATE VIEW v_item_table
AS
SELECT *, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY some_timestamp_col) AS account_id
FROM item_table;
```